# Import obj in Blend fails

Tags: wpf, 3d, expression-blend

When I try to import a obj 3D object in Blend for Visual Studio 2012 it fail with this message:

```
Application: Blend.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Description: The process exited caused by an unhandled exception
Exceptioninformationen: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.WavefrontObjDocumentElementCreator.WavefrontObjLoader.LoadObjFile(StreamReader streamReader, String rootPath, String filename)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.WavefrontObjDocumentElementCreator.CreateElement(SceneViewModel viewModel, ISceneInsertionPoint insertionPoint, String url)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.DocumentElementCreator.CreateInstance(ISceneInsertionPoint insertionPoint, Rect rect)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.FileDropToolBehavior.AddToDocument(DocumentReference documentReference, Point dropPoint, ISceneInsertionPoint insertionPoint)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.FileDropToolBehavior.OnDrop(DragEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.EventRouter.ScopeElement_Drop(Object sender, DragEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DragEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.OleDropTarget.RaiseDragEvent(RoutedEvent dragEvent, Int32 dragDropKeyStates, Int32& effects, DependencyObject target, Point targetPoint)
   at System.Windows.OleDropTarget.MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleDropTarget.OleDrop(Object data, Int32 dragDropKeyStates, Int64 point, Int32& effects)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DoDragDrop(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject, IOleDropSource, Int32, Int32[])
   at System.Windows.OleServicesContext.OleDoDragDrop(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject, IOleDropSource, Int32, Int32[])
   at System.Windows.DragDrop.OleDoDragDrop(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DataObject, System.Windows.DragDropEffects)
   at System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Object, System.Windows.DragDropEffects)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Project.UserInterface.SourceItemNode.OnDragBegin(Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Controls.DragBeginEventArgs)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Controls.DragBeginHelper.TryBeginDragDrop(System.Windows.Point, System.Windows.UIElement)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Controls.DragBeginHelper.DragSourceControl_MouseMove(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Framework.ExpressionApplication.RunApplication()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Blend.BlendApplication.Start()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Application.Main(System.String[])
```

Here u can download the project: http://sdrv.ms/1463KFl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/603954/Inserting-3D-Models-in-Expression-Blend
This is the solution for me :)